# visual studio 2019 xamarin android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

is anyone know if there is keyboard shortcuts to navigate from "@strings/abc" to the strings file or "@color/abc" to the colors file like it is in android studio?

also I would like to know if there is an easy way to extract a hard coded string from the code to the strings file?

thanks,

Comment: You mean you just started in the string.xml file, and then click on the keyboard shortcut to automatically open color.xml?

Comment: no, I meant that when the cursor is on "@strings/abc" you hit F12 and visual studio will take you to the abc key in strings.xml file

Comment: I use Visual studio 2019 Version 16.5.4, and I hit F12 in @string/str or @color/colorAccent, will take me to the key in string.xml or color.xml, you can try.